# Oracle Apex Data Load Definition uploading Ñ character not working

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is it really not possible to upload Ñ character on apex data load definition or I miss some setting?
I am uploading a column text on CSV File with Ñ character but it saves the incorrect value.

Example: I Uploaded NIÑONG.
IT GOES LIKE : NI¿NG.

It replaces the Ñ to ¿ character and removes the next letter after Ñ just like my sample.

Can Someone help me how to correct this?